# Name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Tags: c#, split, parameters, scope, local

I'm trying to test a small piece of code in a totally separate mini project and isolated just this piece, but am getting the following error:

> error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'phoneNumber' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Here's the small piece of code that I'm trying to test out. It seems like it should be pretty straight forward, which is why I'm beyond confused why I keep getting this error.

```
using System;  
  
namespace SplitString  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {   
            string phoneNumber = "AAA-BBB-CCCC";  

            string[] numList = phoneNumber.Split("-");  
            foreach (string phoneNumber in numList)  
                Console.WriteLine(phoneNUmber);  

        }  
    }  
}
```

Expected output should have AAA BBB and CCCC each on its own line. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: You are already using phoneNumber. Try it like this `foreach (string pn in numList)  
                Console.WriteLine(pn);`

Comment: *`foreach (string phoneNumber in numList)`* - phoneNumber is poorly named here, because it's not a phone number, it's part of a phone number. Pick a more accurate name and the problem will go away :D

Answer (score 0):

so you have to change one of the variable either

-> string phoneNumber = "AAA-BBB-CCCC";
-> (string phoneNumber in numList)